# Specify to children of same name in request in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object, soap, soap-client

I need to build a request similar to this:

```
<rooms>
<room>12345</room>
<room>65679</room>
</rooms>
```

However, I insert one room like:

```
$request->therequest->rooms['room'] = 123456;
```

But when I do it again for the 2nd one, it overwrites the first one. How can I specify 2 children 'room' under 'rooms' without overwriting them?

Thanks! This is working with some SoapClient stuff.

Comment: What's with `$request->therequest->rooms[] = 123456;`?

Comment: because that won't give me the type of 'room' then. It will give it a key number instead. I need to pass it as 'room' to the soap server. Not in my control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an array of rooms.
You can add it to the array like:

```
$request->therequest->rooms['room'][] = 123456;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using `SimpleXMLElement`. Then you would just do this:

```
$templateXML = "<rooms></rooms>";
$xmlElement = new SimpleXMLElement($templateXML);
$xmlElement->addChild("room", 12345);
$xmlElement->addChild("room", 65679);

print $xmlElement->asXML();
```

And the output would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rooms>
    <room>12345</room>
    <room>65679</room>
</rooms>
```

Read more about [SimpleXMLElement here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php). And here's some more info on [the addChild method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php).

Answer (score 1):

What about `$request->therequest->rooms['room'][0]` ?